# Using Maven with failsafe plugin to run categorized tests

Tags: maven, integration-testing

I'm looking to run some integrated tests in maven and group them by category using something like this:

Interface:

```
package com.path.for.testing;

public interface SlowTests {

}
```

Test Class:

```
import com.path.for.testing.SlowTests

@Category(SlowTests.class)
public class SlowTest {
    ...
}
```

Pom File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  ...
  <profiles>
    ...
    <profile>
      <id>functional-test-slow-tests</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <groups>com.path.for.testing.SlowTests</groups>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

And I run it with: mvn clean install -P functional-test-slow-tests

My problem is that when it is run it seems to cycle through all tests, not just the ones specified. Does categorization not work on integrated tests? Or am I doing something wrong? I'll update with more information as requested. Any help or direction on this problem is really appreciated, I'm new to this and it's very possible I'm missing something obvious. Thanks.

---

Edit in response to User944849:

When running with a -X argument, I think the failsafe plugin is getting executed multiple times. I've also added the new execution ID that you suggested. This is what I get when the project is built:

```
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.12:integration-test (default-integration-tests)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

...

[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.12:verify (default-integration-tests)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

The tests are using the new ID that you suggested, but I still am getting the same result, i.e. unwanted tests are still running.

Comment: Have you checked to have JUnit 4.7+ configured ? Or do you use TestNG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run with `-X`, do you see multiple executions of the failsafe plugin?  The config shown doesn't include an `<id>` so Maven may be adding your configured execution to its default.  The default runs any tests that match the patterns `**/IT*.java`, `**/*IT.java`, `**/*ITCase.java` .

If that is what's happening, adding an `<id>` to the execution like this:

```
<execution>
    <id>default-integration-tests</id>
    ....
```

will redefine Maven's default plugin execution for the integration-tests phase to do what you want.

---

Update

@Brad, thanks for testing my theory, and @khmarbaise thanks for giving me another idea.

The 2 goal executions are what you should have.  I don't see anything wrong with your config so I checked open JIRAs for the failsafe plugin and I found a [possibly related issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-849) that may be causing the wrong JUnit provider to be used.  If that is what you are running into, you may have to manually specify the JUnit47 provider in the plugin config as defined [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/junit.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've updated my question in response to this. Please take a look.

Comment: Hey, I was out for the weekend and didn't get a chance to respond, but thank you for this, your update identified the problem. I'd actually already tested to see which version of JUnit I was using, but apparently if you don't explicitly specify either the version number or the parallel property, it rolls back to before groups are supported and the group is skipped. Thanks again, I was really pulling my hair out over this one.